# Using a 2 inch pipe to vent a bath fan

Tags: ventilation

Hello I'm looking to install a bathroom vent in a enclosed shower on a GFCI circuit breaker. I know its recommended to use something like a 4 inch vent to vent out the stated flow rate, but since it is not a very big space I would like to use a 2 inch pipe to vent it out and under my house where it is very ventilated.

I know I wont get the ventilation it says on the box but would there be any issues with using a smaller pipe?

Comment: does 'under house' mean a crawlspace? If so, you definitely don't want to do this.

Comment: A 2" pipe would carry less than 25% of the airflow that a 4" pipe would carry, and probably wouldn't be sufficient for any size shower (unless you used some sort of high-pressure fan, which isn't what a bathroom vent fan would be). And to concur with @DA01: dumping the moisture into any sort of confined space would be A Bad Idea.

Comment: Why not just do it right, and use 4" duct. Then run the fan for half as long?

Comment: Since everyone else is piling on, I'll join in with one more problem: it'll be way noisier than the specification.

Comment: They make 3" flex that might be a good compromise if you need to run it in a wall.  Still a significant decrease in cross sectional area, but now less than 50% decrease instead of 75% decrease.

Comment: You mentioned under the house is very well ventilated - can you elaborate? This makes me think it is not a crawlspace, but I am not sure what else it would be.

Comment: So did you use 2" pipe? If so, very Curious to know if the venting works well?

Answer (score 1):

There are probably no concerns in terms of safety. Keep in mind that the capacity of a 2" pipe isn't half that of a 4" pipe. It's *one quarter* the capacity. For that reason, it's going to be hardly worth your effort.

Answer (score 0):

2" may create a back-pressure or air bubble & not vent anything. No harm in just trying it though. However, beneath the house could create mold & even rot issues, if it's not wide open or mostly so, like you're high up on piers. In a crawlspace you'd be adding a wet spot.

Comment: What do you mean by creating an "air bubble"?

Comment: Sorry, I was suspended for a month & figured you wouldn't care at this point, But, I saw your new question so I thought I'd catch-up. An air bubble is when there's an insufficient connection &/or receptacle. The air will just bounce around & almost nothing gets out through the receptacle. Like blowing AT the end of a drinking straw compared to blowing THROUGH the straw.